# Can I grant access to a MySQL user for a single partition of a table?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, access-control

Is there a way, in MySQL, to grant access to a single partition of a table to a specific user? I see no way in the doc for that, but maybe I'm missing it...

Here's a test case:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testing (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE(id) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1000),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
INSERT INTO testing (id) VALUES (2),(20),(200),(2000),(20000),(200000);
SELECT * FROM testing;

CREATE USER 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON my_test.testing TO 'foo'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

-- Now use foo@localhost: you shouldn't see 2k, 20k and 200k values
SELECT * FROM testing;
```

What would the proper `GRANT` syntax be?

Comment: There is no such possibility. Partitions are not privileges scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure you can do what you are after.

I would have thought a better option would be to create a view that only shows the data you want:

```
CREATE VIEW view_testing AS SELECT id FROM testing WHERE id <= 1000;
```

Then give your user only permission to access that view:

```
CREATE USER 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
GRANT SELECT ON my_test.view_testing TO 'foo'@'localhost';
```

(n.b. the user creating the view needs access to the underlying table)

Comment: Indeed, this is an alternative, but since it's a `VIEW`, it seems like you cannot make a FK pointing to it (which I would need for integrity checks), leading to [my SO equivalent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59423197/restrict-a-mysql-foreign-key-based-on-another-column-value-foreign-key-to-a-vi)

Comment: @Xenos - Won't it suffice to have the FK point to the underlying table (`testing`)?

Comment: No, because it would allow the value 200000 to be used (while not being in the allowed view) while still refusing the value 201000 (not in the testing table): so it would make the restricted DB user able to guess the ids in the testing table, meaning the rights are too "relaxed"